# Can someone give examples where a non monotonic function is invertible?

Tags: functions, continuity, inverse-function, monotone-functions

I tried to figure out about examples of non monotonic functions that are invertible but I only got to know that it should be discontinuous to be invertible but could not find any such examples.

Comment: \ $\raise 10 pt{/}$

Comment: There are many, many examples.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ given by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x & x\in\mathbb{Q} \\
- x & x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}
\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $f: [0, 1] \mapsto [0, 1]$ given by

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x & 0 \le x < \frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{3}{2} - x & \frac{1}{2} \le x \le 1
\end{cases}$$